# Checkboxes on email form

Tags: forms, email, checkbox

I am using this email form:
http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

I am not too savvy with PHP, so can any one help me add check-boxes to this form?
For example, there will be 6 items with check-boxes - if the user clicks 3 then only 3 items will appear in the email sent to me.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Checkboxes

You should add checkboxes where you want them to be, inside `<form ...> </form>`, give them different names, for example, I used `name="checkboxone"` for first:

```html
<input name="checkboxone" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/> 
<input name="checkboxtwo" type="checkbox"/>
```

You can use your own memorable names: `name="my_very_own_product"`

### Then in PHP code

This way you can check if they are checked:
note: before "// create email headers" you can still edit email sent.
Mail is sent at line 69.

```php
if (isset($_POST['checkboxone'])) {
    // If checkbox one is checked:
    doSomethingWhenCheckboxoneChecked();
}

if (isset($_POST['checkboxtwo'])) {
    // If checkbox two is checked:
    doSomethingWhenCheckboxtwoChecked();
}

// Here we add selected product to email message body:
if (isset($_POST['my_very_own_product'])) {
    // If checkbox my_very_own_product is checked:
    $email_message .= "My Very Own Product is selected by customer!!\n";
    // Did you notice \n here? It is here for adding line break after text...
}


// create email headers
```

If you need more help just ask for it.

Comment: Did not first read carefully enough and after checking sources again revised my answer, mostly about place where php code should go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it is much appreciated! Very clear and explained well!

Comment: One more question if  you don't mind:
Is there an easy way to create a clear/reset button to clear each text input and check-boxes of content (without a refresh)?

Comment: @TechyDude Check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp (clear button is type="reset")

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't realize it was so simple. Thanks again for all your help Sampo!!!